# MATLAB: Iterate Through a Loop Array

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops

In MATLAB, I need to create a loop to iterate through the entire string array and plot.

In other words, First Iteration: the loop steps to Montana with its value (23,45) and generates plot.

Second Iteration: continue the loop to Georgia with its value (54,75) and plot.

Third Iteration: continue the loop to Texas with its value (55,90) and plot. So, we have 3 different plots for each string.

Here is the array:

```
A = {'Montana','Georgia','Texas'};
```

with X values:

```
X = [23, 54, 55]
```

with Y values:

```
Y = [45, 75, 90]
```

Thanks,

Amanda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
% input data
A = {'Montana','Georgia','Texas'};
X = [23, 54, 55];
Y = [45, 75, 90];

%  plot points
figure(1);
plot(X, Y, 'rx');

% adjust the limits for figure axis
axis([0 70 0 100]);

% label points
text(X,Y, A, 'VerticalAlignment','bottom', ...
    'HorizontalAlignment','right');
```

The output figure
 [image: Output]